# Datetime comparison query

Tags: google-sheets, import, spreadsheet, google-query-language, textjoin

I have an importrange array to get data from alot of sheets. I organise zhem into one list and then make calculations from this list.

WORKBOOK
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OH_LF9r04rRb1ZMuc26CwIq3NQ-qWVlb8mXJwuTechk/edit#gid=28668687

SOURCE WORKBOOK (Tracker)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1huVGusrmhZ60zy9pg59PKN_yfL1XulwvLW5EWwHguvA/edit#gid=2007038591

sheet MODTANEWBIE_QUERY

formula #1 (add UID to DATE):

```
=IF($B$2="No","",ARRAYFORMULA({MODTANEWBIE_PER!A$3&"@"&QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(MODTANEWBIE_PER!$C$3,"Tracker!"&B$3&":"&B$4&MODTANEWBIE_PER!$D$3),"select Col1 WHERE Col1 = "&A2)}))
```

formula #2 (get data from specific column in #Tracker based on date)

```
=IF($B$2="No","",ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(MODTANEWBIE_PER!$C$3,"Tracker!"&B$3&":"&B$4&MODTANEWBIE_PER!$D$3),"select Col1 WHERE Col1 = "&A2)}))
```

For some reason I an unable to query the importrange's Date that corresponds to the cell A2 in _QUERY sheet.

Please am I missing something silly? Is there a format problem?

Thanks alot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formula should be:

```
=IF($B$2="No",,ARRAYFORMULA(MODTANEWBIE_PER!A$3&"@"&QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(MODTANEWBIE_PER!$C$3,"Tracker!"&B$3&":"&B$4&MODTANEWBIE_PER!$D$3),"select Col1 WHERE Col2 = date '"&TEXT(A2, "e-m-d")&"'")))
```

[image]

however:

- tracker sheet does not contain today's date so A2 needs to be a valid date
- dates on tracker sheet are in column B so B4 cant be `A`
- query will then look for `where Col2` where dates are
- and query is picky on dates if they are not in this format: `yyyy-mm-dd`